# gwt maven plugin deploy to standalone tomcat not loading

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, gwt

I'm using the latest gwt maven plugin (https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/index.html) to compile a multi module GWT project and deploy it to tomcat 9. I am also using intellij 14 as my IDE. It's a client app only ie. no server/servlet. When I build via the IDE gwt plugin and zip up and deploy that output to tomcat my app works fine.

However, using the maven plugin, everything compiles ok and the contents of the war look fine to me. The war deploys ok to tomcat, but I simply see a blank page when I try to load it on my browser (latest chrome edition).

I'm running dev tools and jscript console and there are no errors being reported, network view, shows the content downloading ok. I've set break points in my nocache js files and stepped through it with no problems. Below is my pom. I'd appreciated any insight / help with this as it's been bugging me for days..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>guml-ui</artifactId>
    <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
<!--<packaging>gwt-app</packaging>-->


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>myworkspace</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/au/com/guml/ui/components/dashboard/public</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>war</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc-9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.dashboard.Dashboard</moduleName>
                <moduleShortName>Dashboard</moduleShortName>
                <warDir>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui-war-${project.version}</warDir>
                <devmodeWorkDir>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui-war-${project.version}</devmodeWorkDir>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui-war-${project.version}</webappDirectory>
                <skipModule>true</skipModule>
                <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                <startupUrls>Dashboard.html</startupUrls>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-common</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.common.Common</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Common</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-myworkspace</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.myworkspace.MyWorkspace</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>MyWorkspace</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-project</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.project.Project</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Project</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-dashboard</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.dashboard.Dashboard</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Dashboard</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- copy the host html page -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-hosthtml</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui-war-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>war</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-public</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui-war-${project.version}/Dashboard</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/java/au/com/guml/ui/components/dashboard/public</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Cheers,
Matt.

Comment: if it is only a client side app, you do not need tomcat, you can use any webserver by simply copying the compiled files. you can also use Python SimpleHttpServer inside the compiled files directory, if it works then the problem should be some misconfiguration in Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks zakaria, although this wasn't the ultimate solution it did help me to start looking in the right area. Turns out, it was quite a silly error. I was running mvn package on my dashboard module but it wasn't actually running the gwt compiler over it. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is interested I got the maven build working on the multi module gwt project. See the following pom (dashboard) which is my app which inherits other modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>guml-ui</artifactId>
    <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
<!--<packaging>gwt-app</packaging>-->


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>myworkspace</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>guml-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-sources</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final-sources.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/au/com/guml/ui/components/dashboard/public</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc-9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.dashboard.Dashboard</moduleName>
                <moduleShortName>Dashboard</moduleShortName>
                <warDir>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui</warDir>
                <devmodeWorkDir>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui</devmodeWorkDir>
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui</webappDirectory>
                <skipModule>true</skipModule>
                <startupUrls>Dashboard.html</startupUrls>
                <!--<style>PRETTY</style>-->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-common</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.common.Common</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Common</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-myworkspace</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.myworkspace.MyWorkspace</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>MyWorkspace</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-project</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.project.Project</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Project</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-module-dashboard</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <moduleName>au.com.guml.ui.components.dashboard.Dashboard</moduleName>
                        <moduleShortName>Dashboard</moduleShortName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- copy the host html page -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-public</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../gumlui-war/target/gumlui/Dashboard</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/java/au/com/guml/ui/components/dashboard/public</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have to include the build resources entries on this pom and my inherited projects to manually include the public directory, not sure why, this appears to a quirk with the plugin.